# Jade Template not including CSS

Tags: node.js

This is my file structure:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzsTs.png

Inside views, I have layout.jade that has the following code:

```
doctype 5
html
    head
        title= title
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='../bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css')
        script(src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js')
        script(src='../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')
body
    block content
```

This is index.jade:

```
extends layout

block content
      div.top
        form.form-horizontal(method="post", id="loginForm")
          label Username
          input.span3(id="username", type="text", name="User", placeholder="Enter your             username")
          label Password
          input.span3(id="password", type="password", name="Password")
          input.btn(type="submit", value="Log In")
div.container
    div.content
          table.table.table-striped
            thead
              tr
                th Table
                th Heading
    tbody
      tr
        td Blah
        td Test
      tr
        td Hello
        td World
```

div.footer

But it seems like the CSS doesn't get applied because the page looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4ALy.png

The css is in the folder called bootstrap/css

Comment: It would be better if you provided generated html. But I bet you just got css paths wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using express? If so, it seems that you are missing a public folder in your file structure. Usually you have something like:

package.json

app.js

node_modules/

|- ...

public/

|-img/

|-css/

|-js/

routes/

views/

..and you let express know about these file via:

```
var app = module.exports = express();

...

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Try adding that line of code to app.js if it isnt already there, creating the public folder, moving the bootstrap folder there, and referencing it via just link(rel='stylesheet', href='bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') in the jade

Comment: Whoops, I didn't see that before i posted my response :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using an absolute path instead of a relative one. Relative paths can be confusing because they are relative to `app.js` instead of the view.

Change

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')
link(rel='stylesheet', href='../bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css')
```

To

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css')
```

Also make sure you are properly serving static files with a line like the following in your `app.js`:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'bootstrap')));
```